# Rails check if an array exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Sorry for my probably noobish question; I recently started developing with Rails.
I checked through the API, documentation, and did a bunch of searches but could not find what I was look for.

Is there a method to check to see if a specific array exists?

For example,

```
    array = []
    array = [2,3,4]
    if array.exists?
      puts "array exists!"
    else
      puts "No such thing!"
    end
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by exists? Has content?

Comment: No, More like is declared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

like so:

```
if defined?(array)
```

instance variables (eg @array) default to nil, so you can just test them with

```
if @array
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your lightning fast answer!

Answer (score 2):

Note: By defining your array with `array = []`, your array will always exist. But if you want to check if `array` is an Array, you can say `array.is_a?(Array)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
a = [1,2,3]

a.any?
=> true

a.clear

a.any?
=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi fellas i´m newbie at `Ruby` on `Rails` but this is the most simple way:

```
if (defined?(array))
   puts "array exists!"
else
   puts "No such thing!"
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the precise example.